# How Can I remove a bar in beamer?

Tags: beamer, themes

[image]

I'm using beamer theme Berlin, I would like to remove the bar which is shown in white draw the picture below.

Comment: But this is how `Berlin` looks? Is another theme looking better to you?

Comment: @Johannes_B Is there any way I can remove that bar ?

Comment: Probably. I am not a beamer user. I cannot help you. We'll have to wait for someone else to step in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This space is meant to show your subsection title; you can disable it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\makeatletter
\beamer@theme@subsectionfalse%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{sec title}
\subsection{sub title}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]